# Static/fixed background image while page contents scrolls?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to follow a guide located [here](http://davidwalsh.name/css-fixed-position-background-image) to know avail :(.

Here's a link to my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Af/1/

For background; I'm attempting to make it so that the background image stays in the same position while only nested contents of `#container` scrolls, so that the background image is always shown and doesn't have any white-space (edges) when the contents nested in `#container` has a combined height larger than `#container's`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Af/2/

I moved 'fixed' into the bg declaration and it seems to works for me.

Comment: sure thing, sometimes little things like that get you

Answer (score 3):

write `background-attachment` instead of `background-position` Like this:

```
body {
    width: 1000px;
    background: url(http://www.tropicalparadise.net/images/dest/mauritius1.jpg) top right no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/gF7Af/3/